# tf.train.latest_checkpoint returns None after 40K steps on wavenet

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been working on wavenet https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet project. I just needed to restore the model and continue training the model during power off in my computer. If the training is stopped before 30K or 40K steps, It restores the model fine and continues the training. But after 40K steps, it's not restoring the model.

```
tf.train.latest_checkpoint # Returns None for checkpoints after 40K step.
```

I am just wodering what would be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Can you show how the file names look like after 40k steps? Maybe there is an issue with their naming.